# How to get the precise commands that a bash process is triggering?

Tags: bash, scripts, ps

If a bash script running, it will appear in my `ps` output as

```
# ps -e 
[...]
10043 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
[...]
```

**How do I get to know  the precise commands being excecuted?**

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not really a good way to see the precise commands being run inside the bash interpreter from an outsider's point of view to my knowledge.  However, there's a couple of things you can do to learn more about the running process.

- Use [`strace(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/strace.1.html) as the root user to connect to process ID and print system calls in which the process is making.  You can limit the scope of what is output by `strace` with the `-e` option.  For example, to see only write operations which are typically things like `stdout` of a script run: `strace -p 10043 -s99999 -e write`
- Use the [`/proc`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt) filesystem to learn more about a process.  For example, for PID `10043` you can `cd /proc/10043`.  It will contain interesting files like:

  - `environ` file - Contains the environment of the running process.  To view set variables you can run: `tr '\0' '\n' < ./environ`
  - `cmdline` file - will show you exactly the command line arguments of the running process.  You can view these arguments like: `tr '\0' ' ' < /proc/19774/cmdline | sed 's/ $/\n/'`.  [`ps(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/ps.1.html) command also displays this kind of information like `ps -up 19774`.
  - `fd` folder - contains open file handles of the running process.  To view files opened by the process you can `ls -l ./fd/`.  [`lsof(8)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/lsof.8.html) command also displays this kind of information.  For bash scripts, file descriptor `255` typically contains the running script (i.e. `/proc/19774/fd/255`).  This is not always the case.
- Use [`pstree(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/pstree.1.html) to view a process and its child processes to get an idea of the location executing within script.  e.g. `pstree -ap 10043`

## Try it out

Create a `/tmp/daemonwait` with the contents:

```
cat > /tmp/daemonwait <<'EOF'
while sleep 1;do echo hello;done
EOF
```

As a normal user run the script.

```
bash /tmp/daemonwait > /dev/null &
#save the PID for later use
pid=$!
```

Because you started the process as a user you can read the `/proc` filesystem of this process.

Here's some examples from the above description to try.

```
#view the running bash script; press q for quit
less /proc/$pid/fd/255
#view the environment of the running bash script
tr '\0' '\n' < /proc/$pid/environ | less
#watch the process write to stdout or stderr; requires root
sudo strace -p $pid -s99999 -e write
#list the process, child processes, and their args
pstree -ap $pid
```

#### When the script is not file descriptor 255

Exploring when file descriptor `255` is not the script being run.

```
#view all open files of the process
ls -l /proc/$pid/fd/
#notice the daemonwait script is file descriptor 255
```

Let's now treat the `daemonwait` as an executable script.  Note: if you're not using bash as your default shell then you'll need to add `#!/bin/bash` to the beginning of the `/tmp/daemonwait` script.

```
kill $pid
chmod 755 /tmp/daemonwait
/tmp/daemonwait > /dev/null &
pid=$!
```

Let's look again at the file descriptors for the running process.

```
ls -l /proc/$pid/fd/
#notice the daemonwait script is now file descriptor 254
```

#### Clean up

Clean up when you're done playing around.

```
kill $pid
rm /tmp/daemonwait
```

Answer (score 3):

Option 1: Start your script with `bash -x /path/to/your/script.sh`. Bash will then print out each line it is executing, prefixed with a +.

Option 2: use [strace](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Strace): `strace -p 10043` (replacing 10043 with the actual process id of that script). It will tell you what a running script is doing, probably in a lot more details that you need.